# What happends if @Transactional sets isolation level is different from MySQL's isolation level?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-transactions

For example, lets say we have a code like @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE),
,but MySQL has global Isolation level with Repeatable Read,
Question is, how will my springboot code behave?

Comment: The best way is to test it. Run this query and see what it returns: `SELECT @@TX_ISOLATION;` . And I would add a test on this, as depending on spring to behave correctly is usually a costly mistake.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.